# how do get around python the certification error?

Tags: python, macos, ssl-certificate

I am running python3 on Mac Mojavee
I have the following code

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
req = Request("https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_OnQppLqYQ/.well-known/jwks.json")
try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
    print('Error code: ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
    print('Reason: ', e.reason)
else:
    print('good!')
```

when I run it with python3, I get the famous cert error:

```
Reason:  [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
```

I have read so many posts on this here and I am still stuck.

Anyone can help guide me?

Comment: You could pass a `context = ssl.create_default_context()` and set the  `context.check_hostname=False`, `context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE` and pass it with your `urlopen(req, context=context)`

Comment: Try running from the shell:

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla that was the key. thank you answer the question and I will accept

Comment: Try this : https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-fix-python-error-certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-in-mac-os/

Answer (score 1):

Try running from the shell:

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.8/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Replace 3.8 with whatever version you're using.

Comment: I had a certificate issue a few days ago and this worked for me.

Comment: The name of the directory isn't Python.  It's "Python 3.8".

Comment: not there, nothing that starts with python

Comment: Not sure what's going on then.  Sorry.  Maybe search your machine to see if this file is located somewhere else.